# KnockoutJS: Event object

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

This question is related to [KnockoutJS: Tracking menu clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291152/knockoutjs-tracking-menu-clicks). I have been able to tell which menu was clicked by supplying an id value. I need to change this model and use the event.target to obtain additional information. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204806/knockoutjs-click-binding-and-keyboard-modifiers/5204944#5204944) but it does not seem to work. I also created global function `menuClicked`:

```
var viewModel = {};
function menuClicked(event) {
    var id = ($(event.target).tmplItem().data).Id;
    var isActive = viewModel.menuActive();
    if (!isActive || viewModel.currentMenu() == id)
        viewModel.menuActive(!isActive);
    viewModel.currentMenu(id);
}
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'console.asmx/Initialize',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            viewModel = data.d;
            viewModel.menuActive = ko.observable(false);
            viewModel.currentMenu = ko.observable(0);

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }
    });
});
```

And bound the hyperlinks to that method:

```
<a class='${ Class }' data-bind='click: menuClicked'>${ Name }</a>
```

But each time I click the hyperlink, the event object is null/undefined. What I'm trying to do is to retrieve the object used to render the hyperlink as in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/tLnwx/11/) except my hyperlinks do not have ids.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event object is passed to the click binding, but only in the latest Knockout code (so after the 1.12 release).  It will be in the 1.2 release, which should be out before too long.

You can get the latest code here: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/tree/master/build/output

It is quite stable.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you once again!